# How to set a foreign key of an object from a one to many relationship in C# ASP.NET in A Controller

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've got two database models, property and units. There is a one to many relationship between property and units i.e 1 x property has many units. This is not a sql question per say, more I guess of and Object Orientated / ASP question.

At the moment, when a user creates a unit, my modelstate is invalid because the `propertyId` (I think) is null meaning i've got to set the `propertyId` (Foreign Key) of the Units object / model when the units are created in the units controller. I know this is happening in the create function of the unit controller. Maybe I need to parse in the property object here and then set propertyId of the units however, I can't see / access this.

I'm also keen to get some feedback on the implementation i've chosen for this one to many relationship between property and units in the models.

**Property Model**

```
public class Property
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Development Name")]
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Development Address")]
    public string DevelopmentAddress { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Development Description")]
    public string DevelopmentDescription { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Agent Name")]
    public string AgentName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Developer Name")]
    public string DeveloperName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Image Filename")]
    public string ImageFilename { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Anchor Link")]
    public string AnchorLink { get; set; }

    //[Display(Name = "Site Plan FileName")]
    //public string SitePlanFileName { get; set; }

    //[ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    //public virtual IdentityUser User { get; set; }
    public List<Units> Units {get; set; }
}
```

**Units Model**

```
public class Units
{
    [Key]
    public int UnitId { get; set; }

    public string UnitType { get; set; }
    public int UnitNumber { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int Bedrooms { get; set; }
    public int Bathrooms { get; set; }
    public int Carspaces { get; set; }
    public string Floorplantype { get; set; }
    //public int StandardInclusionId{ get; set; }
    //public int OptionalInclusionId { get; set; }
    
    public string Floorplanfilenanme { get; set; }
    public string Unitanchorlink { get; set; }
    public string Internalviewfilename { get; set; }
    public string Rentalappraisal { get; set; }
    public string Contractfilename { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Property Property { get; set; }
}
```

**Units Controller:**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("UnitId,UnitType,UnitNumber,Price,Bedrooms,Bathrooms,Carspaces,Floorplantype,Floorplanfilenanme,Unitanchorlink,Internalviewfilename,Rentalappraisal,Contractfilename,Status,Id")] Units units)
    {             
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            
            _context.Add(units);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("model not valid" );
        }
        return View(units);
      }
```

**Extract of the database:**

[image]

I'm honestly stumped on this, I know what needs to happen but I dont know how to do so. I've researched and I think maybe passing in the property object that has the id so that I can set the propertyId (foreignkey) on the units table but there is not getter or setter on the model.

- What I need to happen:

Each time a unit is created, it is linked by the foreign key `id` to the property table.

Comment: If you have named the property `Id` from `Units` class as `PropertyId` and fill that with the id of the `Property` you like, then everything will work because of naming convention of the Entity Framework. If you did not follow that naming convention you have to wire it up manually - see [EF6 - Relationship Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/conventions/built-in#relationship-convention)

Comment: Makes sense, Do I need to parse in the property object from the property controller to this create method then just set the id from units to the property id?

Comment: Sorry, I did not get what and why you want to **parse** anything.

Comment: I dont think i do have the propertyId available in the units class because i've defined the foreign key for property as id in the units class. I can add the foreign key notation to the units class - Id which i meant to be the key that refers to the property class?